# How to set right permission to Linux file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, passenger

I wanted to know how can I set right permission for my file `/log/production.log`? Everyone is saying just use `chmod` or `chown` but no one explains what I should wright after these commands. I am beginner and would appreciate if you could explain.

In my particular example I have rails app on production server where I need to set permission to `production.log` file in `/var/www/my_app/log/` directory.

Here is what documentation is asking from me:

> By default, Phusion Passenger runs Rails applications as the owner of
>   config.ru. So the log file can only be written to if that user has
>   write permission to the log file. Please chmod or chown your log file
>   accordingly.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: how do you deploy your application?  What is the owner of your `config.ru` file?  `ls -l /var/www/my_app/config.ru`. ?

Comment: I use Passenger + Nginx on DigitalCloud droplet. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 153`

Comment: OK I would look at changing this, since running as root can be dangerous. (In event of compromise, they have run of the server..)

Comment: why exactly is it dangerous? You mean hacking?

Comment: running as root is dangerous since if the process is compromised it has access to the entire machine.  Whereas running as a non priv'd user, when it gets compromised it has access to only that.  I am guessing that it actually isn't running as root, but as www which is non priv

Answer (score 1):

Try `chmod 0660 production.log` and take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/295615) explanation/diagram of chmod.

Comment: This is actually  pretty bad idea, especially on a shared server, since then world has RW access to your logs.

Comment: how about 0660 then ?

Comment: depends on lots of factors., directory logs owned by app user, mode 700 on shared server. so other users can't write to it.  0660 will only work if app user is same group as owner of file.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a deploy user for your application,  say `myapp` (doesn't particularly matter what the name is).   The use this user to deploy/manage your application.  Assuming username myapp

```
 chown -R myapp:myapp /var/www/my_app
```

and then restart nginx/passenger.   This will cause passenger to run as the `myapp` user, and allow it to write logs under the logs directory.  (Also make sure that  you don't have /var/www as the docroot, accessible outside of passenger as it can cause information leakage)

another option, if the server isn't shared, is that you can run as the www user. so

```
chown -R www:www /var/www/my_app
```

which should allow the process to write to your logs.

Comment: first: how can i know if /var/www is as docroot? if it is how to fix it? Secound: how can I register new user (i run your command but now i have permission denied error.

Comment: adduser myapp , is normally how you would add a user, but I don't know much about digital ocean's droplets, or what they run,etc.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

`chmod` allows change the permissions of a file or a directory. Exists three basic permissions (read,write,execute) for three differents groups (owner,group,other).

`chown` allows change who is the owner of a file or a directory.

I recommend you use `chmod 640`. Looking the syntax of `chmod` here you're defining the production.log's owner (usually root) can read and write this file. If you want, you can give read-access for all users of the same group of the owner. But you shouldn't offer permissions for other people, even less in a production environment.